# Checkboxes in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to create a list of options with check boxes. I am using `UITableView` and adding custom type buttons to the table as checkboxes.

My code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is pasted below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
CGRect a=CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 32);
UIImageView *aImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:a];
UIImageView *bImg=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:a];
aImg.image=[[[Resources getResources] getImageLoader] getMainMenuUnselectedImage];
bImg.image=[[[Resources getResources] getImageLoader] getLiveScoreSmallBg];
[aImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[bImg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:a];
[cell.backgroundView addSubview:aImg];
cell.selectedBackgroundView=bImg;
cell.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
cell.selectedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIImage *checked = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_filled.png"];
UIImage *unchecked = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_empty.png"];
UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 30, 30)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_filled.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_empty.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[button setEnabled:YES];
button.tag = indexPath.row;
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 3, 250, 17)];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]; 
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = [teamsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    [button release];
[label release];
[aImg release];
[bImg release];

return cell;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the program, the screen appears without buttons. Also, when I click any row, the program crashes.

Comment: How your buttonpressed method defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're some problems with your code which may be not relevant to your problem, but still...

1. You create cell contents each time cell is reused - so if you scroll your table back and forth the reused cells will contain multiple identical subviews - that's not what you want. To fixed that you must move creating contents to the creating cell block:

   ```
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
       // Create cell contents here!
       ...
   }
   ...
   ```
2. You must not release your button - since you create it with convenience method button is autoreleased

   ```
   button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] 
                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 30, 30)];
   ```
3. This line may also cause problems:

   ```
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ```

   Here you set selector that receives no parameters. If your  buttonPressed method declared is (most common way)

   ```
   - (void) buttonPressed:(id)sender;
   ```

   Then you must create selector as @selector(buttonPressed:) to indicate that it actually takes 1 parameter

Comment: Thanks alot for quick and so useful response. I have made changes by removing release command for the button and changing IBAction to void.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick and useful response. I have made changes by removing release for button and changing IBAction to void. Code works fine now.

Comment: so extra release must have been that problem. IBAction is actually the same as void so it should not make any difference. However I strongly recommend to fix what I pointed at 1st comment as well - if your table is scrollable and has large data then the performance and general look may degrade eventually

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
int i=indexPath.row;


ibutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[ibutton setTitle:@"i" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

ibutton.frame = CGRectMake(430.0,40.0,100.0,60.0);
[cell.contentView addSubview:ibutton];
[ibutton setTag:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"the button tag is %d",ibutton.tag);
[ibutton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailSubView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
addbutton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[addbutton setTitle:@"add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
addbutton.frame=CGRectMake(560, 40, 100, 60);
[addbutton setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView addSubview:addbutton];
 [addbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(addclicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350.0, 60.0, 50.0, 25.0)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 label.text=@"2.99$";
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[label release];

[cell.contentView addSubview:lab];
return cell;
}


-(IBAction)detailSubView:(id)sender{


NSLog(@"working in detail view");
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; 

NSLog(@"%d",button.tag);
a=button.tag;
NSLog(@"%d",a);
  category1* B2 = [[category1 alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *B2Nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:B2];   
  B2Nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  [self presentModalViewController:B2Nav animated:YES];
  [B2 release];
  [B2Nav release];
}


-(IBAction)addclicked:(id)sender{



  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; 

NSLog(@"%d",button.tag);
a=button.tag;
}
```